# How to alert the selected option using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a select tag in my code, here is my code,

```
<select onchange="test(this);">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Select1</option>
    <option value="2">Select2</option>
    <option value="3">Select3</option>
</select>
```

and javascript code is here,

```
<script>
  function test(obj)
  {
     alert($(obj).val()); 
  }
</script>
```

I want to alert the selected text here, If I use the above code the value of the selected option is coming, but I want to alert the text of the selected option can anyone tell to achive this one.
I want to alert it without using any class or id.
I want to alert it only through the obj.

I am waiting for your help.

Thanks In advance

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7QxCF/

Comment: @caramba - read the question again - `I want to alert the text of the selected option`

Comment: @Archer +1 for you answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
alert($(obj).find("option:selected").text());
```

That uses the jQuery object `$(obj)`, like you already had, but does a `find()` which searches the child elements, in this case the selected `option`.

**[jQuery find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**

**[:selected pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
alert($(obj).find("option:selected").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
alert($(obj).find('option').eq(obj.value).text());
```

Working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74tev/)**

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="someid" onchange="test();">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Select1</option>
    <option value="2">Select2</option>
    <option value="3">Select3</option>
</select>
```

javascript>

```
function test(){
   var elem = document.getElementById("someid"),

    var selectedNode = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(selectedNode );
}
```

jQuery>

```
$("#someid").change(){
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").text());
 }
```

Comment: I had a look at the edits and he's editing it to make it correct.  The OP specifically says `I want to alert it without using any class or id` and passes `this` as a parameter into the event handler.  (Not gonna name and shame them - they should have explained why they were changing an answer themselves!)